# Split "100000000000" em JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

Eu preciso separar todos os caracteres de uma string em um array, e tenho um problema, meu código é o seguinte

```
var PISCampos = campos.split("");
```

Quando envio na variavel campos a seguinte string: "011001000000". Tudo funciona, e eu testei com outras como "000001000000" e o split funciona perfeitamente

Porém usando esta string: "100000000000" o split não funciona. eu coloquei um alerta na linha de cima e um na linha de baixo, somente o primeiro funciona com essa string, sugerindo que o erro esta ai mesmo. O primeiro alerta exibe a variável campos, e seu valor esta correto.

**CÓDIGO DE TESTE**

```
alert(campos);
var PISCampos = campos.split("");
alert("teste");
```

**O PROBLEMA**

Eu usava isso para recuperar o valor que lhes falei("011001000000")

```
$("#campo option:selected" ).data("campos")
```

E o meu HTML estava assim

```
    <option data-campos="100000000000" value="53">Bla Bla Bla</option>
```

Só que pelo que percebi, como o primeiro caracter era um numero não nulo, o val() do jquery o considerou um inteiro, falha minha, minhas sinceras desculpas.

**SOLUÇÃO**

```
campos = campos.toString();
var PISCampos = campos.split("");
```

Comment: Ponha o código do teste também, fica mais fácil de localizar o problema. Um [mcve] é fundamental para este tipo de dúvida.

Comment: o problema provavelmente não está na string. Veja aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/z09zxar9/ (abra o console)

vc não tá mandando um int, como no ultimo caso? Isso explicaria.

Comment: Não deu para reproduzir seu erro. Veja: http://codepen.io/bacco/pen/vXQqAN

Comment: Seu teste não roda. Não tem nada dos números que você mencionou nele. Sugiro reler o que é um [mcve].

Comment: Agora entendi o problema, vou fazer uma edição e explicar

Comment: Quando se trata de HTML , "53" não significa que 53 é uma string como aconteceria em uma linguagem de programação. Desta forma, quando você pega esse value, ele irá como 53, e você deverá tratar se é uma string ou não. Se você usa uma função exclusiva de um tipo String, é melhor você garantir que a entrada é uma String : `String(campos)` ou `campos.toString()`, desta forma você garante que  não terá esse problema

Comment: Sim Lucas, eu usei o toString(), muito obrigado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Era pra funcionar, split é uma função da classe String.

Isso **funciona**:

```
var campos = "100000000000";
var PISCampos = campos.split("");

PISCampos.forEach(function(e){alert(e)}); // Somente para mostrar
```

Isso **não funciona**:

```
var campos = 100000000000;
var PISCampos = campos.split("");

PISCampos.forEach(function(e){alert(e)}); // Somente para mostrar
```

Verifique se a variável que você está passando é uma String, e experimente usar um console para ver se está imprimindo algum erro de Javascript (Chrome dev console ou Firebug para Mozilla).

[JSFiddle funcionando](https://jsfiddle.net/krLx5c7g/)